# variable scope outside function in php

Tags: php

I have following scenario

In lookup function i have reach variable, I want to get some of all $follower values in $reach variable.

Below code gives last value of follwer not the sum of all. Where is bug?

```
function x()
{        
    lookup($tweetid,$connection);    
}

function lookup($tweetid,$connection)
{
    $tweets5 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/".$tweetid.".json?count=1");
    $json = json_encode($tweets5);
    foreach($tweets5 as $item)
    {
        $text = $item->text;
        $user_id = $item->user->id;
        $name = $item->user->name;
        $follower = $item->user->followers_count;

        $reach + = $follower; //This does not work
        // $reach = $raech + $follower; //This does not work
        $friend = $item->user->friends_count;
        echo  "Text : $text <br>  ID : $user_id <br> Name : $name <br> Follower : $follower <br> Friends : $friend <br> ---";
    }
    echo "<br> RT reach : $reach"; //This does not give some of folloewer count
}
```

Comment: What you get in $follower variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare variable $reach=0 before `foreach` loop

Comment: This also does not help, still same issue

Comment: What you get in $follower variable

Comment: 12, 14 such integer value. See the parameter here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$reach` variable outside the `foreach` loop first

```
$reach = 0;
foreach($tweets5 as $item)
    {
        $text = $item->text;
..........
...
```

Comment: This also does not help, still same issue

Comment: @Programming_crazy It should work...ok. use the following one. $reach = $reach + $follower;

Answer (score -1):

Just declare `$reach=0` outside foreach loop